# sql server 2005 create temporary table using xml parameter

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to create a temporary table from a xml input parameter.
This is my XML:

```
 <Offices>
        <Group id="22807">
            <Office>185901</Office>
            <Office>185902</Office>
            <Office>185944</Office>
        </Group>
    </Offices>
```

This is my SQL:

```
DECLARE @GroupsOfficeIDs xml
SET @GroupsOfficeIDs = '<Offices><Group id="22807"><Office>185901</Office><Office>185902</Office><Office>185944</Office></Group></Offices>'

CREATE TABLE #GroupOfficeID (PK int primary key identity(1,1), IdXml xml)
INSERT INTO #GroupOfficeID VALUES (@GroupsOfficeIDs)
SELECT PK, 
group.ref.value('@id', 'int') AS GroupID, 
group.ref.value('(Office/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS OfficeID
FROM #GroupOfficeID go cross apply go.IdXml.nodes('/Offices/Group') group(ref)
```

This returns 1 row:

```
PK  GroupID     OfficeID
1   22807       185901
```

I would like it to return the following:

```
PK  GroupID     OfficeID
    1   22807       185901
    2   22807       185902
    3   22807       185944
```

Is it my XML that is wrong or my query?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I got a little bit further...
My query is now this:

```
DECLARE @GroupsOfficeIDs xml
SET @GroupsOfficeIDs = '<Offices><Group id="22807"><Office>185901</Office><Office>185902</Office><Office>185944</Office></Group></Offices>'

CREATE TABLE #GroupOfficeID (PK int primary key identity(1,1), IdXml xml)
INSERT INTO #GroupOfficeID VALUES (@GroupsOfficeIDs)
SELECT PK, 
group.ref.value('@id', 'int') AS GroupID, 
office.ref.value('(Office/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS OfficeID
FROM #GroupOfficeID go cross apply go.IdXml.nodes('/Offices/Group') group(ref)  
cross apply go.IdXml.nodes('/Offices/Group/Office') as office(ref)
```

It produces this:

```
PK  GroupID     OfficeID
1   22807       185901
1   22807       185902
1   22807       185944
```

Why doesn't the primary key increment by 1?

Comment: You are grouping by ID which is giving one result.

Comment: Where am I grouping by ID?

Comment: re-read posting.  Doesn't look like grouping is the issue.  You are correct that PK isn't getting incremented.  You have to create a procedure that auto increments the primary key PK.

Comment: I created the Primary Key field as an autoincrement using identity(1,1).  But this does not increment the column when records are added.

Comment: Did you initially define primary key as auto increment?  See following webpage about changing primary key to auto increment : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the same value for `PK` because the temp table stores one XML data in one row with one PK, which means all data that come from the same XML source will have the same primary key :

```
CREATE TABLE #GroupOfficeID (PK int primary key identity(1,1), IdXml xml)
                                --  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                --  here you associate one XML data to one identity id
```

You may want to alter temporary table structure to store one `GroupID`-`OfficeID` combination as one row instead :

```
CREATE TABLE #GroupOfficeID (PK int primary key identity(1,1), GroupID int, OfficeID int)
```

Then the query for insert would be like so (avoid using keyword like `GO` and `GROUP` for alias!) :

```
INSERT INTO #GroupOfficeID(GroupID,OfficeID)
SELECT
    g.value('@id','int') GroupID,
    o.value('.','int') OfficeID
FROM @GroupsOfficeIDs.nodes('/Offices/Group') grp(g)
     CROSS APPLY g.nodes('Office') office(o)
```

Then `SELECT * FROM #GroupOfficeID` will produce the correct expected result :

```
PK  GroupID     OfficeID
1   22807       185901
2   22807       185902
3   22807       185944
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/272)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  BTW..didn't know there was such a thing as SQL Fiddle!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, that's very useful for SQL questions : [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2998271)